# Puppeteer.js - passing array from .addScriptTag to .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, webautomation

I am making scraper using puppeteer, and i made js script which stores some data in array (and when I use it in console in browser it works)... But when i try to store it in JSON file using fs.writeFileSync i got error... This way works in the same scraper i made using nightmare.js. 
I assume that I passing array in a wrong way (for puppeteer), and I am not sure what to do. 
Problematic code:

```
await page.addScriptTag({path: 'script.js'}).then((array) => {  fs.writeFileSync('data'+i+'.json', JSON.stringify(array));
  console.log(array); })
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`addScriptTag` doesn't return the script result but the `ElementHandle` representing the generated `SCRIPT` tag.

What you could do is add that script tag, exposing a function and then call that function using the evaluate function:

```js
await page.addScriptTag({path: 'script.js'});
const array = await page.evaluate(() => someFunction());
await fs.writeFileSync('data'+i+'.json', JSON.stringify(array);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really couldn't understand because it is different from nightmare.. You are lifesaver!